# Can't Import Tensorflow 2.3

Tags: tensorflow

i am using Windows 10 and installed Tensorflow via Anaconda using:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Using this code to check if tensorflow was installed correctly:

```
# tensorflow
import tensorflow
print('tensorflow: %s' % tensorflow.__version__)
```

I am getting the following error when importing tensorflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Muril\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deep_versions.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Muril\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Muril\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Muril\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\Muril\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Muril\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Muril\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Any ideas in how to fix this? Here some aditional info:

```
(base) C:\Users\Muril>python -V
Python 3.8.3

(base) C:\Users\Muril>pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.3.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
```

Comment: I have had better success using conda to install tensorflow. Conda automatically installs the Cuda toolkit and Cudnn. Pip does not install these..Give it a try conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

Comment: Did you look at the link which is in your error? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

Answer (score 0):

Edited code for TF 2.6 Version.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
print('tensorflow: %s' % tf.__version__)
```